# Is there any solution to run the react native application with expo go again?

Tags: react-native-reanimated

The error message is:
node_modules\expo\AppEntry.js: .plugins[0] must be a string, object, function

The AppEntry.js file is:

import registerRootComponent from 'expo/build/launch/registerRootComponent';

import App from '../../App';

registerRootComponent(App);

I'm trying to run my app by the command npx expo start -c after installing react-native-reanimated but I can't

Comment: What do you get if you run `npx expo-doctor`? What do you have in the `plugins` array in `app.json` (replace sensitive info with "xxx" before posting). What does your `babel.config.js` look like?

Comment: I'm getting a similar error after updating from expo SDK 48 to 50. Were you able to pinpoint an issue?

Answer (score 0):

```
The error message is: node_modules\expo\AppEntry.js: .plugins[0] must be a string, object, function

If you have bootstrapped react-native app with - npx create-expo-app project_name

This error is caused by the dependency package version (package.json) which is conflicting in nature with the version of expo installed.

Suppose the Expo version is: "expo": "~50.0.4",

Check always this two "@react-navigation/native": "^6.1.6",
"@react-navigation/native-stack": "^6.9.12", suppose you are using ^6 version then don't use another version like 5 for the same packages
```

-> For styling if you are using NativeWind install one version less than Tailwindcss

```
If anybody instantly needs to work on rn project use this dependency(no one knows when the package will update again)
"dependencies": {
    "@expo/webpack-config": "~19.0.1",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^6.1.6",
    "@react-navigation/native-stack": "^6.9.12",
    "axios": "^1.3.5",
    "expo": "~50.0.4",
    "expo-status-bar": "~1.11.1",
    "nativewind": "^2.0.11",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "18.2.0",
    "react-native": "0.73.2",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "^2.14.1",
    "react-native-heroicons": "^3.2.0",
    "react-native-reanimated": "^3.6.2",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "4.8.2",
    "react-native-screens": "~3.29.0",
    "react-native-web": "~0.19.6",
    "tailwindcss": "^3.3.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.20.0",
    "babel-plugin-module-resolver": "^5.0.0",
    "deprecated-react-native-prop-types": "^4.0.0"
  },
  "private": true
} ``
This will work for sure and if you need some other module don't install the latest version just check the older version and then install it.
```